# Spring configuration in JBossWS

Tags: spring, jboss, jakarta-ee, jbossws

I'm trying to expose a web service using JBossWS (native stack) and also take advantage of Spring's dependency injection. Here is a scrubbed down version of my code:

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">

    <display-name>Test Service</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener> 
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
    </listener> 

    <servlet>    
        <servlet-name>EndpointService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.blah.webservice.EndpointService</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:load-time-weaver />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.webservice" />
</beans>
```

**EndpointService.java**

```
package com.blah.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 

@Service
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class EndpointService {

    private TestService testService;

    public EndpointService() {}

    @Autowired
    public EndpointService(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;        
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String endpointEcho(String echo) {
        return echo;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String serviceEcho(String echo) {
        return testService.serviceEcho(echo);
    }
}
```

**TestService.java:**

```
package com.blah.webservice;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 

@Service
public class TestService {

    public TestService() {}

    public String serviceEcho(String echo) {
        return echo;
    }
}
```

When I build this and deploy to JBoss, it starts up just fine and I can see Spring is pre-instantiating my classes but when I issue calls to the web service, endpointEcho works as expected while serviceEcho throws a NullPointerException. It seems that when JBossWS instantiates the endpoint class, it isn't finding out about my Spring configuration. Is there a simple way that I can tell JBossWS about Spring? I feel like I'm either missing some very small detail, or I'm approaching this all wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service must extend SpringBeanAutowiringSupport to be able to take advantage of the autowiring support.

Comment: I tried that. Attempting to make a call to testService is still giving me a NullPointerException. It appears that the autowiring is taking place, but maybe in the wrong context.

Comment: So I tried this again (third time's a charm, right?) and it appears to be working. I moved the @Autowired annotation from the endpoint class's constructor to the individual property declarations, and now I'm rocking and rolling. Thanks!